# How to disable tslint check in VScode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am not enable typescript in my react project , and I just import optional chain to my project,it works but vscode keep gaving me an syntax error. I have checked all my instlled extentions, no tslint. so I don't know where the error comes from and how can I disabled this syntax checking?

[image]

---

update:

`VS Code 1.41 supports optional chaining in both JavaScript and TypeScript files. This support includes syntax highlighting and IntelliSense.`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530234/11454633

this resolved my problem.just upgrade vscode to the latest version

Answer (score 4):

Inside vscode `ctrl + p` / `command + p` (Win/Mac)

```sh
>open settings (JSON)
```

Add to setting.json

```
{
  ... // other rules
  "typescript.validate.enable": false,
}
```

Update: If you are using typescript, directly set it as above is good enough.

For javascript, refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823743/disable-tslint-in-vscode) from comment, thanks

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
}
```

> The files are JS so it's "Javascript validation". But this validation is done via the underlying Typescript engine. Could be a bit confusing.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this not works for me. in fact I have tried : `"javascript.validate.enable": false`  and it wroks. from this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823743/disable-tslint-in-vscode.

Comment: Have you defined the type or interface for variable test?

Comment: @devspeter no I don't becasue I am not using typescript